# Изменить шрифт для всего приложения

Tags: java, android, шрифты

Пытаюсь подключить свой шрифт для приложения. Но он подключается, только если я поверну экран или уйду на другую активити. При загрузке приложения шрифт не поключается. И почему то на эмуляторе смена шрифта вообще не работает (на настоящем телефоне хоть крутить надо, а на виртуальном никак).

UPD.
этот код работает на API 19. а на API 22 не работает.

Создал класс

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;

public final class FontsOverride {

    public static void setDefaultFont(Context context,
                                      String staticTypefaceFieldName, String fontAssetName) {
        final Typeface regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                fontAssetName);
        replaceFont(staticTypefaceFieldName, regular);
    }

    protected static void replaceFont(String staticTypefaceFieldName,
                                      final Typeface newTypeface) {
        try {
            final Field staticField = Typeface.class
                    .getDeclaredField(staticTypefaceFieldName);
            staticField.setAccessible(true);
            staticField.set(null, newTypeface);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

В MainActivity

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TypefaceUtil.overrideFont(getApplicationContext(), "SANS_SERIF", "font.otf");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

В styles.xml

```
<item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
```

Comment: Вот то, что "MainActivit" оно конкретно где находится?

Comment: @Эникейщик исправил в вопросе. куда я уже только не пробовал его пихать...